# Hexagon Sphere (wait!) with specified number of hexes?

Tags: modeling

Have read the many posts on hexagons to a sphere, with the icosphere -> subsurf -> node removal and limited dissolve which gives me a (mostly) hexagon tesalated sphere.

BUT

it determines the number of hexagons based on the initial icosphere settings and they are basically twice as many or half as much as I need.

Changing subsurf doesn't help obviously as only one input provides hexagons.

So I need 352 hexagon faces on my sphere (yes, inclusive the 12? pentagons too)

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Approximating spheres to triangles/hexagons is based on existing platonic solids like the icosahedron or its subdivisions, so you will always obtain number of faces which are multiples of the base solid. You can't just arbitrarily subdivide into a specific number of polygons, it is mathematically impossible, as far as I know

Comment: Yes, I consider it's a function of the edges and as such limited.
However, I'm trying to create a golf ball and they have (crudely) 352 faces (which are then turned into dimples) so it is possible in the physical world obviously. Maybe a different starting sphere type?

Comment: There are a couple of tutorials teaching to model a golf ball using some 3d programs including Blender. Did you try some of them?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TW7WwUfAYxM

Comment: Yes, I've seen the tutorials, they are not accurate both in terms of the number of dimples AND the shape of the dimples (made by non golfers I'm assuming).

This is why I added the "(wait!)" into my title. It's not a "how do I model a golf ball" question, it's more specific. Namely an ico with 4 renders 642 dimples, an ico with 3 renders 162 dimples. I need closer to 352 dimples.

Comment: You should really change the title to "how to model a geometrically perfect golf ball" and then add to the body of the question your comment about why the tutorials are not good enough (wrong geometry). Because that's what you're asking.

Comment: Robin understood what I was asking in geometry terms and answered accordingly.
What happens if a future forum user wants a specific number of hexes on a sphere but knows nothing about golf or golf balls? What will they search for? Not "golf ball" I would wager.

Comment: For information, icosahedron based geodesics can have 162, 252, 362, 492, 642
 etc but not 352.

Comment: Saying you need a sphere with exactly 352 faces for a golf ball is nonsense, sorry. I don't know where you got the number from, because actually the amount can vary between 300-500 dimples depending on brand and model. 352 happens to be the amount on a quite popular model, the  Titleist Pro V1 so maybe that's where it's from. But as the number of dimples varies a lot, so does the size of them as well. And they are not even always circular in shape, the Callaway HX for example has hexagonal dimples. An overview: https://www.independentgolfreviews.com/how-many-dimples-are-on-a-golf-ball/

Comment: Maybe this is interesting to create a pattern from scratch: [European Patent Application, Golf ball dimple pattern](https://data.epo.org/publication-server/html-document?PN=EP0159550%20EP%200159550&iDocId=245610)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shipped add-on 'Add Mesh: Geodesic Domes' gets pretty close with the settings as shown:

[image]

Use <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve to get rid of the triangulation of planar regions, leaving you with hexagons and pentagons.

Faces:362. 350 hexagons, 12 pentagons.

Comment: That's close enough Robin, amazing stuff! Thank you so much!

Now I need a cheat to select the centre vertex of each planar hex?

Comment: @dwbell ..  See edit. Is that what you mean? if you wanted to put some center-vertices back, you could  Shift-G select similar to get the hexes, and then Face menu > Poke those faces, stashing a vertex group if you need to.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, I didn't realise Limited Dissolve would do that.

Many many thanks for the help Robin, this is awesome stuff.

Comment: I'd say that's a good result, as I said my comment below the question it is nonsense to insist on the number 352, as the dimples on balls vary. Of course if you want to model a specific ball where you know the amount you might want it to be perfect, but that's not said in the question ;)